# What does .dist used as an extension of some source code file mean?

Tags: naming-conventions, naming

Examples in the Zend tutorial:

- phpunit.xml.dist
- local.php.dist
- TestConfig.php.dist

Comment: A one million DOGEs question.

Comment: Cross reference: [What is the meaning of the /dist directory in open source projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22842691/367456)

Answer (score 63, accepted):

`.dist` files are often configuration files which do not contain the real-world deploy-specific parameters (e.g. Database Passwords, etc.), and are there to help you get started with the application/framework faster. So, to get started with such frameworks, you should remove the `.dist` extension, and customize your configuration file with your personal parameters.

One purpose I have seen in using `.dist` extension, is to avoid publishing personal data on VCSs (say git). So, you, as the developer of a reusable app, would use your own configuration file, but put the de-facto get-started config data in a separate `.dist`-suffixed file. (See [Symfony2](http://symfony.com/doc/2.2/cookbook/workflow/new_project_git.html)'s documentation, 4th part)

Comment: In Zend 2 ".dist" files can contain default configuration but are not meant to be removed. Do you for what words does "dist" stand ? "Distribution" ?

Comment: It stands for "Distributable"

Comment: Not your fault, just FYI:  It looks like that Symfony has reverted their approach on `.dist`  files after the referenced 2.2 version. We can only do the educated guess that is because they got it turned wrong: .dist in a repository distributed contains the default or the example and the user can override that file with a file of the same basename (e.g.: repo: `.env.dist`, user: `.env`; or e.g.: repo `phpunit.xml.dist`, user: `phpunit.xml`). Compare @AsTeR May 2013 comment which has the Zend Framework example that has the correct forward path of distributing (not backwards as Symfony 2.2).