# What is the meaning of the /dist directory in open source projects?

Tags: github

Since I first saw a `dist/` directory in many open source projects, usually on GitHub, I've been wondering what it means.

With `dist`, `vendor`, `lib`, `src`, and many other folder names that we see quite often, I sometimes wonder how I should name my own folders.

Correct me if I'm wrong!

- src: Contains the **sources**. Sometimes only the pure sources, sometimes with the minified version, depends on the project.
- vendor: Contains other dependencies, like other open source projects.
- lib: Good question, it's really close to `vendor` actually, depending on the project we can see one or another or both...
- dist: From what I saw, it contains the "production" files, the one we should use if we want to use the *library*.

Why is open source so confusing? Isn't it possible to do things clearer? At least per language because some languages use specific names.

Comment: Another good answer can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23730882/what-is-the-role-of-src-and-dist-folders).

Comment: I really should get into the habit of including this in my git repos, instead of worrying about building jars after 3 years of not working on something.

Answer (score 440, accepted):

To answer your question:

#### **`/dist` means "distributable", the compiled code/library.**

Folder structure varies by build system and programming language. Here are some standard conventions:

- `src/`: "source" files to build and develop the project. This is where the original source files are located, before being compiled into fewer files to `dist/`, `public/` or `build/`.
- `dist/`: "distribution", the compiled code/library, also named `public/` or `build/`. The files meant for production or public use are usually located here.

  There may be a slight difference between these three:

  - `build/`: is a compiled version of your `src/` but not a production-ready.
  - `dist/`: is a production-ready compiled version of your code.
  - `public/`: usually used as the files runs on the browser. which it may be the server-side JS and also include some HTML and CSS.
- `assets/`: static content like images, video, audio, fonts etc.
- `lib/`: external dependencies (when included directly).
- `test/`: the project's tests scripts, mocks, etc.
- `node_modules/`: includes libraries and dependencies for JS packages, used by Npm.
- `vendor/`: includes libraries and dependencies for PHP packages, used by Composer.
- `bin/`: files that get added to your PATH when installed.

Markdown/Text Files:

- `README.md`: A help file which addresses setup, tutorials, and documents the project. `README.txt` is also used.
- `LICENSE.md`: any [rights](https://choosealicense.com/no-permission/) given to you regarding the project. `LICENSE` or `LICENSE.txt` are variations of the license file name, having the same contents.
- `CONTRIBUTING.md`: how to [help out](https://github.com/blog/1184-contributing-guidelines) with the project. Sometimes this is addressed in the `README.md` file.

Specific (these could go on forever):

- `package.json`: defines libraries and dependencies for JS packages, used by Npm.
- `package-lock.json`: specific version lock for dependencies installed from `package.json`, used by Npm.
- `composer.json`: defines libraries and dependencies for PHP packages, used by Composer.
- `composer.lock`: specific version lock for dependencies installed from `composer.json`, used by Composer.
- `gulpfile.js`: used to define functions and tasks to be run with Gulp.
- `.travis.yml`: config file for the [Travis CI](https://travis-ci.com) environment.
- `.gitignore`: Specification of the files meant [to be ignored](https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/) by Git.

Comment: What about the meaning of `dist`?

Comment: distribution, it usually contains the compiled software.

Comment: What about the `assets/` folder? What is supposed to contain?

Comment: @Sekhemty, static content like images, video, audio, fonts etc.

Comment: & public meant for ? app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public')); ?? app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist')); is not a good idea

Comment: And about `inc/` or `include/` or `includes/`, what does these should contain?

Comment: @Vadorequest um, it's in the answer

Comment: As an aside, the hier(7) man page, which describes the filesystem hierarchy on Unix systems, can be a source of information for path names.

Comment: Should i also include `css` and `js` inside `assets` folder?

Answer (score 88):

To answer your original question about the meaning of the `dist` folder:

The shortform `dist` stands for `distributable` and refers to a directory where files will be stored that can be directly used by others without the need to compile or minify the source code that is being reused.

**Example:** If I want to use the source code of a Java library that someone wrote, then you need to compile the sources first to make use of it. But if a library author puts the already compiled version into the repository, then you can just go ahead. Such an already compiled version is saved into the `dist` directory.

Something similar applies to JavaScript modules. Usually JavaScript code is minified and obfuscated for use in production. Therefore, if you want to distribute a JavaScript library, it's advisable to put the plain (not minified) source code into an `src` (source) directory and the minified and obfuscated version into the `dist` (distributable) directoy, so others can grab the minified version right away without having to minify it themselves.

**Note:** Some developers use names like `target`, `build` or `dest` (destination) instead of `dist`. But the purpose of these folders is identical.

Comment: I think this best answers the question. dist stands for distributable, not distribution. It is the directory that once everything ha been compiled, gulped, transpiled, assembled and produced from all the other sources and files and trinkets etc.. this is what you want to distribute or indicate to others that it is the distributable!

Answer (score 4):

Summary of the folders:

- bin: binaries
- contrib: contributions to the project
- dist: -- see 1. and 2.
- doc/s: documentation
- include: headers (C/C++)
- lib: libraries (C/C++)
- man: short for man/manual pages (Unix/Linux), *c.f. `man(1)`*
- src: source

---

1. *"/dist means "distributable", the compiled code/library."* [ref.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22844164/367456)
2. *"The shortform dist stands for distributable and refers to a directory where files will be stored that can be directly used by others without the need to compile or minify the source code that is being reused."* [ref.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33051731/367456)

Answer (score 3):

Actually, "dist folder" is the result you get after modifying source code with "npm run build" or "ng build" or "ng build --prod" for production.

Meanwhile, after getting a "dist folder", there might still be few a things that you still need to do depending on your project type.

Comment: It is perhaps worth to mention that _actually(!), **it depends**_ . Technically on the node package manager (npm) script named _"build"_ which the `npm-run` command runs. In practice, this differs (a lot), we've seen in node projects the preference of the directory _"build"_ - and not _"dist"_ - for example, while having the _"dist"_ folder already available before any npm build script has been run (e.g. a clean checkout).