# Meaning of :dist

Tags: gruntjs

I was curious about the meaning of the word dist: within the context of a grunfile.js for example

```
grunt.initConfig({
  sass: {                              // Task
  dist: {                            // Target
  options: {                       // Target options
    style: 'expanded'
  },
  files: {                         // Dictionary of files
  'main.css': 'main.scss',       // 'destination': 'source'
  'widgets.css': 'widgets.scss'
   }
  }
 }
});
```

Many thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the meaning of the /dist directory in open source projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22842691/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-dist-directory-in-open-source-projects)

Answer (score 1):

'target' or 'output' would be more apt, but they use dist, short for distributed or distribution. I think it's a bit of holdover lingo because the source is typically Dev files, and the end result is what you might push for distribution in a nodejs package.

Answer (score 1):

dist is the acronym of **distribution**