# What does all files and directories in most repositories mean?

Tags: github

I'm quite new to GitHub and get's quite confused by all the files and folders and files extensions I have never seen before.

Just taking a look at a repository, I see for example this:

- [FOLDER] dist
- [FOLDER] src
- [FOLDER] test
- [FILE] package.json
- [FILE] gulpfile.js
- [FILE] bower.json

These are just some of the files, and folders I see around. What does all of this do? Do I need to use some kind of pre-made structure if I want to distribute my own code? Everyone seem to be doing it so, what happens if I do not structure my repos like this?

Is there any convention guide / style guide that I have missed?

Answer (score 1):

Directory and file structure are **different** for each programming language and build system. Typically, people follow these conventions:

- `dist/`: distribution, which normally contains the compiled software (contains minified code)
- `src/`: source, contains the source files of the software
- `build/`: contains code that is not minified and not ready to be deployed for production
- `test/`: contains the test files of the repository
- `package.json`: describes the package (in JavaScript/npm)
- `gulpfile.js`: file that acts as a manifest to define tasks in the program
- `bower.json`: used to define a Bower package so you can create your own package which contains all of the dependencies for your software

You can find more about the styling conventions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22842691/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-dist-directory-in-open-source-projects) and [here](http://blog.rangle.io/angular-gulp-bestpractices/).

EDIT: You can look up project structure for specific languages. For example, [this](https://blog.risingstack.com/node-hero-node-js-project-structure-tutorial/) can be helpful for a Node.js project.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the answer. Is there any conventions around html, php, javascript that I could try to follow? Those are the three main languages I would do projects within. 

If I make a plugin for WordPress or any other CMS, should I follow a convention there as well, or it's more relaxed when its more specific repositories?

My main fear is creating a repo, that other people cannot use because I did not follow some sort of convention or similar. Possible that is just a non-real fear though. 

Thanks.

Comment: You shouldn't really be that worried about people not being able to use your repository. If you really want to religiously follow a convention, you could use [Google's JavaScript style guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javascriptguide.xml). I would recommend looking at known JavaScript/PHP/HTML/Wordpress plugin repositories and try to mimic their project structure.