# SCSS script creates nested css directories when saving files

Tags: css, sass, directory, node-sass

I have a watch function which outputs scss code to a css directory, but I'm unsure why sometimes the files are saved in another nested css directory like such:

```
public/
  sass/
    css/
      css/ // this directory shouldn't exist
        style.css //saved here
      style.css //and here (should only save here)
  style.scss
```

this is my script: `node-sass -w src/public/sass -o src/public/sass/css`

Comment: Do all your sass partials begin with an underscore?

Comment: don't have any partials... all super basic scss files

Answer (score 0):

have you tried adding a `/` at the end of your source directory or path? See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31448114/how-to-compile-or-convert-sass-scss-to-css-with-node-sass-no-ruby)

Try running this script:

```
node-sass -w src/public/sass/ -o /src/public/sass/css/
```

I recommend changing your CSS path into a directory named `/dist` for best practices.
See this [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22842691/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-dist-directory-in-open-source-projects/22844164)

example:

```
node-sass -w src/public/sass/ -o /dist/public/css/
```