# The "output" file genereated in angular after running ng build is the same as "dist" file?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, angular-cli

I am new to angular, and I am following a guide to help me deploy my app to S3. In the guide when the author runs "ng build" it generates a "dist" file, but when I run it generates a file named "output". I just wanna know if they are the same thing.
Thanks!!

Comment: You mean a folder? in that case ng build by default builds your project into a dist folder. Yours is named differently, in that case you can check your `angular.json` file for the build dir under project_name -> architect -> build -> outputPath

Comment: Yes, a folder. I guess it is the same thing then. I have the following on my angular.json file: "outputPath": "output",

Comment: It makes sense, your outputPath is set to output, did you change? in any case you can change "output" to "dist" or much better imo to "dist/project_name"

Comment: I will do just that! Thank you very much @Amineze

Answer (score -1):

**output** is as a result of running **ng build** it is correct to say that they are the same thing only that one is as a result of the other as explained above.
The **outputPath** is used to show where the files which have been compiled can be found.
More information can also be found in this link.
 [Angular files directory explanations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22842691/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-dist-directory-in-open-source-projects)